# Draw a line using core graphics when touch moves in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

how do I draw line when moving finger across screen in iPhone using core graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the touch events:

**on touches began:**

record the point & save it in an instance variable

**on touches moved:**

record the new ending point & save it in an instance variable

With these 2 points you can create a path & use Coregraphics to draw the path

Comment: i am drawing but it's slow on device and fast on simulator